# Using maven version in plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

I am writing a plugin to Maven. I want to customize action depend on Maven version (person's who use my plugin)
something like:

```
if (MavenVer == "2.2.1") 
    //do some things
if (MavenVer == "3.0")
//do another things
```

I found out build-helper-maven-plugin but i'm not shure how to use it to do this job.

Comment: Can you elaborate which kind of action is different for Maven versions?

Comment: i'm using external plugins which have different API for mvn2 and mvn3. So I need to recognize it at the runtmie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for an answer to your question and I have come to the conclusion that there is no simple way to get the maven version, or at least I couldn't find it. The best I was able to find is that the maven-enforcer-plugin contains code that looks up the maven version. However in looking at the maven-enforcer-plugin source code it is a little complicated and involves getting a handle to a RuntimeInformation instance through plexus (the IoC container used by Maven).

I recommend you take a look at the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/enforcer/tags/enforcer-1.1.1) and see if you can use what they did. Pay particular attention to RequireMavenVersion and EnforcerMojo classes.

Answer (score 1):

you need to inject maven reference into plugina and simply check version using API
http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-project/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getVersion()

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getVersion()

code for injection

```
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
/**
 * @component
 */
ArtifactFactory factory;
/**
 * @component
 */
ArtifactResolver artifactResolver;
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"
 */
List remoteRepositories;
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${localRepository}"
 */
ArtifactRepository localRepository;
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project}"
 */
MavenProject mavenProject;
```

Comment: getVersion which you mentioned above gives me version of MY plugin: 1.0-SNAPSHOT. I need to know version of Maven, which run my plugin.

Comment: what is the version of pluging and what is the version of project? i guess the problem is that the current version of pluging 1.0-SNAPSHOT and as long as you attaching pluging to your plugin project only, i getting 1.0-SNAPSHOT. I assume you will get actual project's version once your plugin will be attached to "real(not plugin)" project

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what I meant. Let me explain: When you go into "Download" section on http://maven.apache.org/ you can see there are three avaible versions. Maven 3.0.4, Maven 2.2.1, and Maven 2.0.11. I want to know which one one these are used to attached my plugin to  "real(not plugin)" project  :)